# How can I add description to plantuml object that contains another object?

Tags: plantuml

Is it possible to add text description to a plantuml object which contains another object?  I see how this can add additional text:

```
@startuml

rectangle rect [
This is a <b>folder
----
You can use separator
====
of different kind
....
and style
]

@enduml
```

And I can add an object inside an object:

```
rectangle sb3crect {

rectangle rect [
This is a <b>folder
----
You can use separator
====
of different kind
....
and style
]

 component sb3c [
 QA QMgr: QAMBSB3C
 ]
}
```

Which, the latter diagram produces:

[image: Rectangle inside rectangle]

However, the existing diagram I'm trying to replace has a lot of description in objects (whether they're rectangles, nodes, components, etc) which contain other objects, such as this:

[image]

(Highlight added to illustrate the additional text).

Is there a way to do this in plantuml or would those just be notes outside of the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a floating note inside your node or package. Don't forget to give your note an alias like `as n1` or it will not work.

By default, it will align horizontally with the component, which you can change with the command `left to right direction`.

I added `skinparam componentStyle uml2` because that is the style in your example but that is, of course, optional.

```
skinparam componentStyle uml2
left to right direction

node "<<device>>" {
note "hello World!" as n1
[Group Message] as gm
}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  I knew there must be some kind of way, this will work fine, appreciate your help.